# Post to multiple twitter accounts PHP

Tags: php, twitter, oauth

i HAVE read many Tutorials on posting to twitter using `OAuth` like [here](http://www.snipe.net/2009/07/writing-your-first-twitter-application-with-oauth/) but i am still unclear on some things.

My requirements is to **tweet through multiple accounts for each of which i have a username/password**.

Is this possible ? If yes then how do i do it?
I am confused how to get the 4secret keys required for each user account that i have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1.` PHP Class: https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

`2.` PHP Function

```
function tweet($status, $consumer_key, $consumer_secret, $user_token, $user_secret){
    include("class.twitter.php");
    $tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
        'consumer_key'=> $consumer_key,
        'consumer_secret' => $consumer_secret,
        'user_token'  => $user_token,
        'user_secret' => $user_secret,
    ));
    $tmhOAuth->request('POST', $tmhOAuth->url('1/statuses/update'), array(
      'status' => $status
    ));
}
```

`3.` https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new (register an app, get keys foreach account)

`4.` `tweet("yay!", ...);`

`5.` goto 4 but with different keys

Comment: ok. so if i did register an app with my base account (say). Then how do i get the app keys foreach account?

Comment: @ayush, register your app/website again with each account to obtain keys for that account, I think that will work with no problems. There is no base account, since they are not connected.

Comment: thanks a lot. But i don’t want to make application registration for each twitter account rather than my single account.
so please tell me proper guidance to do that….How it will be done?

Comment: @ayush, I don't think that's possible, since username & password means nothing now, before September 1 2010, you could just enter username and password to post to Twitter, but now things are different, probably to prevent spam, and what you are trying to do :) Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on Twitter's [authentication](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/auth) scheme, and then have a look at some [libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries#php).