# post a tweet to multiple accounts php

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

am trying to create a php script that post tweets to some users

i use that php class to do that
https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth

but how can i post a tweet to multiple accounts in the same time

i use this code but it sand to one account only

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('library/twitteroauth.php');

$ConsumerKey = "xxx";
$ConsumerSecret = "xxx";
$oauth_token = "xxx";
$oauth_token_secret = "xxx";

$connection = new TwitterOAuth($ConsumerKey, $ConsumerSecret ,$oauth_token , $oauth_token_secret);

//$twit_body = $_POST['twit_body'];

$twit_body = 'تجربة للجميع022222222';

$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', array('status' => $twit_body) );

//$status = $connection->send($twit_body);

print_r($status);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need different oAuth Tokens to achieve this. They are unique for each user.

Please go through this link: [Post to multiple twitter accounts PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906549/post-to-multiple-twitter-accounts-php)

Answer (score 0):

You'd need different oauth tokens, they are assigned on a per-user basis.

Comment: Is the answer still valid in 2023? I understood https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token such that one can post to multiple users now